# C# List of runtime Type (petapoco)

Tags: c#, sql, database

Trying to customize my petapoco experience, I have following situation:

```
class Animal
{
// common properties
}

class Dog:Animal
{
//particular properties including custom attributes for properly working with DB
}

class Cat:Animal
{
}
```

Normally, I use

```
List<Dog> ret = db.Query<Dog>("select * from dogs").ToList();
```

I created a list (Category) which keep tracks between tables in database and objects actually implemented in my code (eg. class dog)

So I obtain the type at runtime from Category list:

```
Type t = ((Category)Categories.Current).ObjectType;
```

In my debugger I can see the `Dog` type for t. But I don't know how to convert the runtime obtained type into something usable for

```
List<t> ret = db.Query<t>("select * from ...").ToList();
```

Thanks in advance,

PS. I don't want to use base Animal for query List since the result list will populate a `GridView` and derived classes (eg. Dog) contains specific attributes for displaying, filter, etc.

Comment: Maybe you could use reflection to call `Query` too? ([This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/232621) might help, which case this is a duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method).)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is to have something like this:

```
public static IList FetchAllByCategory(Type category)
{
    string sql = "select * from " + category.Name + "s";
    if (category == typeof(Dog)) return db.Fetch<Dog>(sql);
    if (category == typeof(Cat)) return db.Fetch<Cat>(sql);
    ...
}
```

Note that you cannot use `List<Animal>` as return type, as a list of a derived type is not assignment compatible to a list of a base type. `IList` is the greatest common denominator here. But there is a chance that the GridView actually sees the *real* `List<T>` assigned to its data source. (Usually data binding sources are typed as `object` anyway.

`Fetch<T>()` is like `Query<T>` but returns a `List<T>` instead of a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

@Gábor Bakos thanks.

Well, I found a way but required to add a dummy virtual GetObjects() in Animal class, then override GetObjects() for each Dog, Cat and so on.

```
Type type = ((Category)Categories.Current).ObjectType; // get type
object rtObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // create instance
((Animal)rtObject).GetObjects(); // call some known base method
```

But this rise the question: do I need this complicated way?

I think I can just make a GetObjects() with hard coded switch by type, then call the real methods.